# Listening on port being used

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

Is there any way to listen to traffic on a specific port that another program is currently using, through the python `socket` module? For example:

```
                           |--> my program
external request -> Host ->|--> intended program
```

I am not looking to send back a response to the request, I simply want the traffic. I was looking at using the `socket.SO_REUSEADDR` method, but I think that's simply to avoid having to wait for the socket's timeout, not to allow another listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket.SO_REUSEADDR option helps both applications to be bound to the same port and to receive packets destined for that port. So, I am not sure what you mean by your timeout note in the question. The only catch is that for some of the platforms, including Linux, both the sockets must set SO_REUSEADDR, else, the second socket not be able to bind. So, if you cannot modify the intended program (let us say, it is a standard third-party program), then using SO_REUSEADDR might be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

see http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing

to use it in your own python program, you'd have to import the sniff command

```
from scapy.all import sniff
a=sniff("tcp and port 1337")
```

sniff has various options (callback functions, timeout, number of packets etc)

Comment: is there any standard library function for this? I would prefer to stay away from external libraries.